# Why does this if/else statement always execute the if branch?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I know that there exists `.slideToggle()` but I want to add more features later.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, sliding up works but I cannot slide down.

Can I not overwrite my var? Would be very nice when somebody can help me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var resizeValue = true;
    $(".resizeSelect").click(function () {
        if (resizeValue === true) {
            $(".resize").slideUp(

            function () {
                $('.parent').height($('.child').height('100'));
            });
            var resizeValue = false;
        } else {
            $(".resize").slideDown(

            function () {
                $('.parent').height($('.child').height('100'));
            });
            var resizeValue = true
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: have you tried to put in some consol / alert logs, to see where the code hangs ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't redefine the `resizeValue` variable within the `click` function. Just remove `var` from `var resizeValue` (it should only be used at the top of the `ready`-function).

Comment: This points to this answer about pass-by-reference in JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Answer (score 6):

Because you are redeclaring your variable resizeValue in your function instead of update it :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var resizeValue = true;
    $(".resizeSelect").click(function () {
        if (resizeValue === true) {
            $(".resize").slideUp(

            function () {
                $('.parent').height($('.child').height('100'));
            });
            //DO NOT DECLARE NEW VARIABLE WITH VAR
            resizeValue = false;
        } else {
            $(".resize").slideDown(

            function () {
                $('.parent').height($('.child').height('100'));
            });
            //DO NOT DECLARE NEW VARIABLE WITH VAR
            resizeValue = true
        };
    });
});
```